# Monitor Throughput on Nokia IP560

Tags: throughput, checkpoint

I am planning on replacing our pair of Noka IP560s running CheckPoint. I need to size the replacement accurately so i need to see the maximum throughput the Firewall has ever had to deal with. I can look in SmartView Monitor and get the current throughput but is there a "high water mark" option?

The Nokias are running Check Point R71 and SmartView Mointor is 75.20. Thoughts?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have monitor license for the firewall you can check historical throughput graph from SmartView Monitor (System counters – FireWall History). Historical throughput averages over time, so use the shortest timeframe for more accurate results. Without license your options are to use a third party tool for polling the interfaces or keep staring the Network Activity page.